# Simulate mouse click to window instead of screen

Tags: cocoa, macos, mouse

Is it possible in MacOS X to send a mouse click to a specific window?

I already managed to send a click to the entire screen via `CGPostMouseEvent`. 
The windows i want to control overlap each other, so my next idea was to bring the proper window to the front before triggering the click. It works but ends in a total mess... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to send events to Cocoa applications via the undocumented

```
CGEventPostToPSN
```

Here is some code sample from Dave Keck. He posted a little application [on the mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2009/Apr/msg00764.html).

```
customEvent = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType: [event type]
                                 location: [event locationInWindow]
                            modifierFlags: [event modifierFlags] | NSCommandKeyMask
                                timestamp: [event timestamp]
                             windowNumber: WID
                                  context: nil
                              eventNumber: 0
                               clickCount: 1
                                 pressure: 0];

CGEvent = [customEvent CGEvent];
CGEventPostToPSN(&psn, CGEvent);
```

To archive it, i pasted [more source code](http://pastie.org/476682) on pastie.org

For reference: The whole [thread on cocao-dev mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2009/Apr/thrd8.html#00708)

Answer (score 1):

You can use probably use the [Accessibility APIs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityLowlevel/).

It's a bit more complicated, but it should work.

Comment: As far as i know, you can only send AXAktion items. No mouse clicks.

Comment: Why does it have to be a mouse click specifically? Sending AXPress to, say, a button should work just fine.

Comment: This does work, but note that you should be careful to test if the application window is hidden; it can break accessibility in my experience.

Comment: The button is a graphical element and has no AXAktions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the [Window Manager API: SetUserFocusWindow()](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Window_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SetUserFocusWindow) and then create the mouse event.

Comment: I already did this via AXAction: "AXRise". But it ends in a flickering mess of windows.